# What this post_class function is doing in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, grid, wordpress-theming, responsiveness

```
<? php post_class('col-md-4 col-md-6 grid grid_2_column grid_3_column'); ?>
```

i have this code in wordpress them I don't know how this function works and what it is doing please explain what this function is doing, so i can modify it according to me needs.

Comment: Have you tried googling it? It is probably in the wordpress documentation

Comment: yes, it is probably in the docs. Yet if you are going to ask on Stack Overflow, you need to include the code you are asking about instead of expecting others either already know what it looks like, or googling online and hunt it down so that they can help you.

Comment: @RasmusRosengren yes, but I understand nothing from documentation

Comment: @HolyMoly I have added the code that i need to understand

Comment: from the docs: `it will print out and add various post-related classes to the div tag` so what it is doing is adding those classes you see to div that the  post lives inside. if it is inside a loop, it is adding it to each post

Comment: in this case, it is using bootstrap classes. if you want to change it just change it, however make a backup of the original code so that if you mess up you can restore it - or create a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

post_class() function is used to print out default post-related classes to the div tag and you can add various finer CSS classes for their post styling.

In your example, you are adding various classes for your post styling.